# Not able to run testng tests in perallel with POM.xml

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, pom.xml

I need some help for executing parallel tests using pom.xml.

Information: 
We have a test automation framework for testing ecommerce website.
There is a separate class for handling all the webdriver operations and instance creation which has a static webdriver.

Question: We were able to run the parallel tests by just using pom.xml (fork count). while since we have introduced testng to our framework -> Now I have included testng.xml in the pom.xml and right now it doesn't consider the pom configuration and only consider the testng configuration and opens only 1 browser instead of 3. Please let me know if anybody have faced the same issue?

```
Pom.xml -
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>planet.sports.TA</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.13.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.53.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11-beta3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-hc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.gmail4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmail4j</artifactId>
            <version>0.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.22.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                    <parallel>tests</parallel>
                        <forkCount>5</forkCount>
                        <!-- TestNG suite XML files -->
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.5.1</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.7</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Custom suite123" verbose="3" parallel="classes" thread-count="3">

<test name="test run1" >
            <classes>
            <class name="AmazonTest" />
            <class name="AddToCartTest" />
            <class name="BankPaymentTest" />
            </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: You were told in the beginning that, you are using static web driver instance. It may be the issue because even though you set parallel in testng, you all test are pointing to single web drive instance as it is static. Try to use thread local web driver.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by Murthi, you should separate the browser instances in the `@BeforeClass` annotation (for example), this way each thread will have its own driver and be able to function independently. Multi-threading a test is a design approach, not just a parameter change.

This might give you some direction: https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Parallel+Testing+in+Java+with+Maven+and+TestNG